Cannot make the DHCP Server of Adguard Home to work
I bought a mini-pc to start experiment a little bit with homelab. My plan is to setup Home Assistant, Adguard Home and Nextcloud as a starting point. All those, through proxmox. The router I have is locked from the provider and I cannot add a custom DNS. The router is also locked on VOIP and I cannot replace it. I have 2 options. Either add a second router to bridge with the first and connect all my devices there OR disable the DHCP server from the router and use the one from Adguard.
I enabled Adguard Home, add on the VM network the static IP and as the Gateway IP the IP I had in my router admin. I enabled DHCP and did the same in the settings (Gateway IP and same Range of IP addresses as on the router). I disabled the DHCP server from the router. Then after flushing DNS in my devices, I stopped having access on the internet.
I also tried the following:
I disabled DHCP on Adguard and shutdown the VM. Then I made a reset on my router and made sure that I had the DHCP server enabled. I changed my device WiFi settings to a specific IP and I was able to connect to the internet.
Edit: As requested, here is the content of the etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp1s0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.2.37/24
        gateway 192.168.2.1
        bridge-ports enp1s0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

iface wlo1 inet manual


It looks like AdGuard Home is a DNS Server. NOT a DHCP server. Are you mixing them up?

They also have an option for DHCP Server. Here is a screenshot from Google, since I don't have access right now to my own setup. https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1372058/194966487-adeff10b-205f-41ef-bf53-43f68ab1e6e1.png

What exactly did you configure as Adguard's own gateway, and what exactly did you configure as the gateway to be advertised via DHCP?

On the GatewayIP I added the IP of my router (192.168.2.1) and the range of IP addresses were the same as in my router setup 192.168.2.2 up to 250.
Then on my VM (proxmox) setup, I added the IP of the Adguard, which was like this 192.168.1.34/24 and the Gateway IP same as the router IP above.

It sounds like this AdGuard VM hasn't been made to join the physical LAN with bridged networking? (Instead it is attached to some "NAT bridge"?)

10.22.22.x nor 192.168.2.x nor 192.168.1.x an be reached outside of your network. So it would not be reachable from work.

@TomYan I am not sure, since my skills around networking are google-based only. But the Network type I see on the proxmox for the VM is named as vmbr0. Not sure if it helps

@Ramhound I don't want my VM to be reachable outside my network. That's supposed to be a homelab, so I don't want to risk anyone get access to my camera or sensors :)

I understand that but your question is “home to work” that suggests your a machine in your home and a machine at work must talk.

@Tasos I'm pretty sure vmbr0 is a NAT bridge (especially if it's a/the default bridge that is available ootb). If you want the VM to serve as the DHCP server in your physical LAN, you'll need to create a so-called "external bridge" on the proxmox host, i.e., a bridge with a physical NIC that is enslaved to it. (It could be a bit tricky to set up if you are managing the proxmox host over network instead of keyboard and screen though.) Both that bridge on the proxmox and the vNIC in the VM should be assigned with an IP within the LAN subnet (e.g. 192.168.2.253 and 192.168.2.254).

@Ramhound Ohh that's a misunderstanding. The service is called "Adguard Home" and what I mean is that I cannot make it work. Nothing about my home and my workplace.

@TomYan I have my proxnox in a mini-pc and I can currently access it through my main pc and an IP in my browser. But I can easily connect a monitor and keyboard to do stuff. Is there any online tutorial or video I could check to do it? I am not skill-full on those tasks (hardware/network)

@Tasos Actually I could be wrong. It seems that proxmox could have set up an external bridge: https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Network_Configuration#_default_configuration_using_a_bridge Do you have similar content in /etc/network/interfaces? You may want to add yours to the question. (Seems like it really depends on a choice your made during installation?)

@TomYan Just updated my question with the content of the /etc/network/interfaces

Hmm, so it looks fine. When you disable DHCP server on the router and enable that in AdGuard, can your LAN devices obtain an IP from AdGuard? If so, have you checked the details of IP configurations they received? (Including default gateway and DNS server)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
